# How to update the values of an attribute of many objects in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy arrray of **N** objects of class Particle `p = [Particle, Particle, ...]` where each object has an attribute `pos` and `vel`, each an array `[x,y]`, all floats. I was wondering what the most efficient way to update the values of all the `pos` and `vel` attributes in the array is.
I want to run the following update a lot to a large array of particles, where `acc` is an 2D array, **N** lots of `[x,y]`:

```py
for i,body in enumerate(p):
    body.vel -= acc[i] * timestep
    body.pos += body.vel * timestep
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to change each position and velocity attribute of the elements of p other than setting the value of each `pos` and `vel` element by element, using the respective acceleration element. It seems like there must be a pythonic way to do this.

I would like something like `p[:].pos` to have access to an array of the `pos` values.

Comment: Your object dtype array is similar to a list. This approach does not take advantage of numpys numeric code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [numpy.recarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) will help you here. Use `recarray` instead of `ndarray` is more to meet your requirements. `recarray` allows field access using attributes. Some sample codes here:

```
acc = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
timestep = 1
paticle_num = len(acc)

arr = numpy.recarray(paticle_num, dtype=[('pos', float), ('vel', float)])
# initialize
arr.pos = numpy.arange(paticle_num)
arr.vel = numpy.arange(paticle_num)

# operate in the whole dimension easily, I think that is what you want.
arr.vel -= acc * timestep
arr.pos += arr.vel * timestep
```

I just treat `pos` and `vel` as float to simplify the problem, if they are floats like `[x, y]`, it is just something like that.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I want. I'm struggling to work out how it would work if `pos` is an array [x,y]. I'm getting `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (3)` if I just treat `pos` as a float as you did, but type (float,float) isn't a thing.

Comment: Hi, @JJenne, dtype seems not support float array, the easiest solution is that split `pos` into `pos_x` and `pos_y`. Is that ok for you?

Comment: if this is the answer you want, please accept my answer, I'm new here too, I need the reputation, thanks : ) @JJenne

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `pandas.DataFrame`.

I made a few implementations to compare the speed. Your option right now is almost the same as having a simple Python list with `Particle` objects.

```
import random
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Particle:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel):
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Particle({:.2f} | {:.2f})'.format(self.pos, self.vel)

def f1(data, acc, time_step=2):
    for i, p in enumerate(data):
        p.vel -= acc[i] * time_step
        p.pos += p.vel * time_step

    return data

def f2(data, acc, time_step=2):
    df['vel'] -= acc * time_step
    df['pos'] += df['vel'] * time_step

    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n1 in (10**1, 10**3, 10**5):
        particle_list = [
            [random.random(), random.random()]
            for _ in range(n1)]
        acceleration_arr = np.random.random((n1, ))
        acceleration_arr_2 = acceleration_arr.reshape((n1, 1))

        # option 1
        particle_list_1 = [
            Particle(pos, vel)
            for pos, vel in particle_list]

        # option 2
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            data=particle_list,
            columns=['pos', 'vel'])

        # assure results are equal
        ret_1 = f1(particle_list_1, acceleration_arr)
        ret_2 = f2(df, acceleration_arr)
        # convert to lists
        ret_1 = [(p.pos, p.vel) for p in ret_1]
        ret_2 = [(p['pos'], p['vel']) for _, p in ret_2.iterrows()]
        # print('ret_1', ret_1)
        # print('ret_2', ret_2)
        assert ret_1 == ret_2

        # compare duration
        repetitions = 100
        t1 = timeit.timeit(
            'f1(particle_list_1, acceleration_arr)',
            'from __main__ import f1, acceleration_arr, particle_list_1',
            number=repetitions)
        t2 = timeit.timeit(
            'f2(df, acceleration_arr)',
            'from __main__ import f2, acceleration_arr, df',
            number=repetitions)
        print('n={:10d} | {:30s} {:.6f}'.format(n1, 'list with for-loop', t1))
        print('n={:10d} | {:30s} {:.6f}'.format(n1, 'pandas.DataFrame', t2))
        print()
```

Running this code gives me this output, showing that the `pandas` version is a lot faster as the size of the data grows:

```
n=        10 | list with for-loop             0.001032
n=        10 | pandas.DataFrame               0.064379     # pandas is slower

n=      1000 | list with for-loop             0.106632
n=      1000 | pandas.DataFrame               0.067613     # pandas is faster

n=    100000 | list with for-loop             9.986003
n=    100000 | pandas.DataFrame               0.115627     # pandas is a lot faster
```

Of course, my sample implementation is not exactly what you described, but it shows that there is a faster way to do what you intend.